# Rust futures -- use Box::pin or pin_mut outside futures::select

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I had read the usage of futures::select, but I encounter an obstacle. here is my confusion: At the part of `expression` in `select!`, we should use a type implementing `Unpin` and `FusedFuture`, but here `Pin` on a `Unpin` is no effect accoring to usage of `Pin`.

1.why we should wrap `Pin` on a `Unpin` if call `fuse()` outside a `select!`, if it have no effect 2.why a `Pin` could be used in expression of `select!` and pass the checker if there needs a `Unpin`.

here is code:

```
async fn async_identity_fn(arg: usize) -> usize {
    arg
}
let fut_1 = async_identity_fn(1).fuse();
let fut_2 = async_identity_fn(2).fuse();
let mut fut_1 = Box::pin(fut_1); // Pins the Future on the heap
pin_mut!(fut_2); // Pins the Future on the stack
let res = select! {
    a_res = fut_1 => a_res,
    b_res = fut_2 => b_res,
};
```

here is some link

[usage of `Pin`](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html) ;

[confusion about usage of `Pin`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AGlm.png)

[usage of `select!`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/macro.select.html)

[confusion about condition of using select!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0O29.png)

Comment: Why do you think `Pin` is not allowed on an `Unpin` type? What does "1. why Pin on a Unpin" mean? What do you mean by "2. why a Pin could be used in expression of select!"? I have troubles understanding your meaning.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 1. that's because of this summary which is at the bottom of [link](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html) .  2. because at the doc of futures contains such a word "Futures directly passed to select! must be Unpin and implement FusedFuture.".  if you have toubles to understand, you can look my links listed under my question. I don't know how to express more clearly. It's really appreciated for your patient answear.

Comment: The link you gave does not say `Pin` with `Unpin` type is forbidden, just that it is useless. But I still don't understand your first question: "why `Pin` on `Unpin`" is not a question - why what? As for your second question, are you asking why `Pin` is allowed if `Unpin` is required? That's because `Pin` on `Unpin` is useless, doing nothing but not interfering.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for your feedback and answear again. according your supposition, I consider what I really want to know and revise my question.

Comment: "why we should wrap `Pin` on a `Unpin` if call `fuse()` outside a `select!`" I don't see you pin the future.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In the [doc](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.21/futures/macro.select.html), there is such a word "If a similar async function is called outside of select to produce a Future, the Future must be pinned in order to be able to pass it to select. This can be achieved via Box::pin for pinning a Future on the heap or the pin_mut! macro for pinning a Future on the stack.".  So, I don't know whether we must do the same as this, or it's just a best practice. And the above  code is copied from this doc.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman maybe we are talk about the different crate, It's different feature(`select!`) between futures and tokio. because when I talk with others, they also think of tokio at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

> why we should wrap `Pin` on a `Unpin` if call `fuse()` outside a `select!`, if it have no effect

Because it is not `Unpin`:

```rust
error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:3:49: 5:2]>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/lib.rs:12:15
   |
12 |       let res = select! {
   |  _______________^
13 | |         a_res = fut_1 => a_res,
14 | |         b_res = fut_2 => b_res,
15 | |     };
   | |_____^ within `futures::future::future::fuse::_::__Origin<'_, impl futures::Future<Output = usize>>`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:3:49: 5:2]>`
   |
   = note: consider using `Box::pin`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl futures::Future<Output = usize>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl futures::Future<Output = usize>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<impl futures::Future<Output = usize>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures::future::future::fuse::_::__Origin<'_, impl futures::Future<Output = usize>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Unpin` for `futures::future::Fuse<impl futures::Future<Output = usize>>`
note: required by a bound in `futures_util::async_await::assert_unpin`
  --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.21/src/async_await/mod.rs:50:24
   |
50 | pub fn assert_unpin<T: Unpin>(_: &T) {}
   |                        ^^^^^ required by this bound in `futures_util::async_await::assert_unpin`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::select_internal` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

So it is not valid for `select!`. However, even for `!Unpin` value, if we pin it the pinned value does implement `Unpin` (not because of `Pin` itself but because `Box` and references are always `Unpin`).

> why a `Pin` could be used in expression of `select!` and pass the checker if there needs a `Unpin`.

Because the macro can pin the result of the call itself. However, when using variables directly it cannot do that soundly.

Comment: if it means that we doing something, the same as my first question, is just want to pass the checker?

Comment: @sunboy_zgz What question (or answer) are you talking about?

Comment: In order to remove the compiler error, we would pin the `Unpin`, combining with your answer I regard that this action is only to pass the checker. Is this correct?

Comment: @sunboy_zgz There is no `Unpin` type in your question.

Comment: `Fuse` type implement the `Unpin` Trait

Comment: @sunboy_zgz Only if the underlying future does. This is equivalent to no implementation at all.

Comment: thank you, maybe I need to learn more about the underlying details.